# Can't create non-advertised shortcut in InstallShield 2012 Limited Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield, installshield-2012, advertised-shortcut

I've created an InstallShield 2012 Limited Edition installer project for a Visual Studio 2012 solution. I've configured in to create a "Send To" shortcut. However, it creates an advertised shortcut, so Windows doesn't actually display it in the "Send To" menu.

When I created the shortcut in the installer project, I explicitly chose the "shortcut" option rather than the "advertised shortcut" option, but it creates an advertised one anyway.

How can I make the installer generate a non-advertised one?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to achieve the same goal by creating a shortcut using the option "New Shortcut to Preexisting File."

I then typed in the name of the EXE that would be created by the primary output and it was able to create a Send-To Shortcut with a non-advertised target.