# MSI installer vs. user profile creation

Tags: c#, windows, installation, windows-installer

The problem occurs when a windows user profile is created *after* installing our tool with the MSI installer.
When starting the tool with the new user, Windows wants to start the .msi file again.
(When the installation was run from a network path, Windows is then unable to find the installer)

The installation only installes 5 files (exe, dlls, txt) and creates a link on all users desktop.

**Questions:**
What is the reason why windows wants to run the installer again?
Is this the default behavior?
How can I prevent windows from starting the installer again with new users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this occurs when you click the shortcut, perhaps the advertised shortcuts have been created by the installation program and it tries to install the feature on demand. The differences between the types of shortcurts are described [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/20/from-msi-to-wix-part-10-shortcuts.aspx). If it is your installation program you can try using non-advertised shortcuts in project. If you are talking about third-party software you can try creating your own shortcut for the installed executable.

Comment: It's my own installer, but its the Visual studio thing, not WIX. 
Thanks for the link, but I struggle how to set the shortcut 'non-advertised' in Visual Studio. Do you have any hints?

Comment: Perhaps, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772859/how-to-use-non-advertised-shortcut-on-product-output-in-installshield-limited-ed) will help you

Answer (score 1):

Note that this repair to add the missing something should occur just once per new user to restore the data. If it happens more than that it's something more serious.

Even if you modify the shortcut, there is still the issue that if this new user (or any user) does anything that triggers a repair the same thing will happen. Repair is available from right-clicking the MSI file, and maybe from Programs&Features too. You really should keep the MSI file available.

If it's an accident that you didn't intend then why not just fix it? Look at the event log MsiInstaller event log entry, that might help. Also, Visual Studio may have added something that it thinks you need, like an extra HKCU registry entry - I believe that's been reported as an issue. You may find something in Orca or even in the setup project's UI in the HKCU registry.

Comment: Well, in my case there are only a few files to install. The link only goes to all users Desktop. And for this specific tool there are ony a few well known people that receives the installer.  The described problem just confuses the users, so I'd like to know how to fix this.

Comment: I can't add anything more except that this has been reported before, and as I said, the MsiInstaller event log entry may tell you what component was repaired, and an examination of the MSI file with Orca or even the registry view in the setup projects IDE may help. VS setups tend to add default settings in HKCU.